# attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats' in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roles, rank, roblox, leaderboard

```
local garbage = game.Teams["Glizzy Garbage"]
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

if player.leaderstats.Pounds.Value <= 1000 then  --this is the line that the output is detecting the error
    player.Team = garbage
end
```

I am trying to make it where when the player reaches a certain amount of 'pounds' then they will automatically receive a roll. I've searched through many youtube videos and haven't found a fix or an alternative way to do this, and I'm not sure why this isn't working. This script is located in the workspace. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LocalPlayer` object is only exposed in LocalScripts. Because you're using a Script in the Workspace, you'll have to access the `player` object another way. It's also a good idea to handle this kind of logic inside a function that is fired any time the Pounds value changes.

Try using the [game.Players.PlayerAdded](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Players/PlayerAdded) signal :

```
local garbage = game.Teams["Glizzy Garbage"]

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local Pounds = player.leaderstats.Pounds
    Pounds.Changed:Connect(function(value)
        if value <= 1000 then
            player.Team = garbage
        end
    end)
end)
```

Comment: This will only trigger if the player joins the game. I assume they want to watch the value of leaderstats.Pounds. So should probably do the team switch when incrementing Pounds

Comment: Ah, good catch. I'll update with a handler for value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is just

```
local plrStage = plr.leaderstats.Stage.Value
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

try instead of putting team name put team colour

also use

```
player.Team.Service = garbage
```

end)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).